# Edge cases with jquery autocomplete or twitter typeahead

Tags: knockout.js, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I need help with twitter’s typeahead. I’m also open to using any other autocomplete that works with knockout. For example these look nice just not sure if they can do what I need (https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-jqAutocomplete and https://www.npmjs.com/package/knockout.autocomplete)

**Background Info**
I have JSON data coming from backend and this is used to autocomplete on in an input field. Let’s say it looks like the following:

```
[{
   Name:”John Smith”
   Id:23
 },
 {
   Name:”Jane Doe”
   Id:298
 },
 …
]
```

I do autocomplete on the name field and send back to the server the name and id of the selection (or entered text) when the input field loses focus (or when user uses the submit button)

So here is my scenario. I have 3 cases for autocomplete:

1. User selects a name from suggestions and then sends the name and id for that selection back to server
2. User types in input field and no option is available from autocomplete; so user types a new name that is not in the options that autocomplete knows about. In this case, when input field loses focus, it sends to the back end the new name and an id of -1 and makes autocomplete/typeahead pull the new data from the backend (bc it needs to know what the id of the newly created name is so that future autocomplete requests can be done on it)
3. User types in a name that appears in suggestions from autocomplete, but the user doesn’t select the name from the options instead it keeps typing the name out. This is equivalent to selecting the name except that it doesn’t trigger the ‘selected’ event so I don’t know the id for that name… unless I go through all the names and check if they match… but don’t know how to get the array of options that twitter’s typeahead is using for autocomplete so I need to make another request to the server so this won’t work.

**Question**
I’ve been able to do case #1 and #2 with twitter’s typeahead and no knockout.
How would I implement case #3? I used to check on the backend that the name sent from front end is not in the database, so this was a name comparison – thing is I’d need to index the names column. I’d prefer to do a check by id, but I’m open to suggestions. I’m also open to changing the design from autocomplete/typeahead to something else that deals with my 3 cases.

Comment: Maybe catch the render events and see if the latest suggestions contain the final typed name?

Comment: You can catch the onkeypress and the blur event on the input and manually trigger a click for your case #3